# How can I make a histogram of year values with labels every year?

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I have a list of years I want to make into a histogram in Altair. I want one bin per year.

This is what I can make so far:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import pandas as pd
import pdb

alt.renderers.enable("altair_viewer")
my_years = [2010, 2011, 2011, 2015, 2012]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"year": my_years})  # , parse_dates=["Date"])
df["year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["year"], format="%Y")
mychart = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X(
            "year(year):Q",
            # bin=True,
            bin=alt.Bin(divide=[1]),
            timeUnit=alt.TimeUnitParams(unit="year", step=1),
            # type="temporal",
            axis=alt.Axis(
                format="%Y",
                # tickCount="year",
                # tickMinStep=1
                # values=list(range(min(source["year"]), max(source["year"]), 1)),
            )
            # axis=alt.Axis(tickCount="year")
        ),
        y="count()",
    )
)

mychart.show()
```

[image]

I want to make it look more like this mockup:

[image]

For Y, I tried this but it didn't work:

`y=alt.Y(field="year", aggregate="count", axis=alt.Axis(tickMinStep=1))`

As a bonus, the first bin should be the minimum year and the last bin should be the max year.

Note the commented out code, I've tried a few ways to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds more as if you want to create a bar chart of counts rather than a histogram. Is there any specific reason for the binning , or would the following fit what you need?

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd


my_years = [2010, 2011, 2011, 2015, 2012]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"year": my_years})  # , parse_dates=["Date"])
df["year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["year"], format="%Y")

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x="year(year):O",
    y=alt.Y("count()", axis=alt.Axis(tickMinStep=1)),

)
```

[image]

Comment: I want gaps in years with no observations, to preserve the time-based nature of it. (ex. 2013 should show count=0 with a gap on the graph). If I have to generate fake data or something to achieve that, that's an option. Like aggregate each observation into: {2011: 2, 2012: 1, 2013: 0, ...}

Comment: @JimmyCarter Yes I think explicit zero values is your best bet. I tried setting `values` of the x axis and `range` of the x scale, but it doesn't work with empty ordinal values it seems. You can see an example of what you want in this comment https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/619#issuecomment-374860824

Answer (score 0):

You need to hack around Altair's desire to omit non-existent observations. And treat the years as strings. I couldn't find anything for centering histogram ticks so it has to be a bar chart.

The rest I think can be handled with documented Altair options.

For more advanced empty-date handling, see github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/619#issuecomment-374860824

via @joelostblom

[image]

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import pandas as pd
import pdb


def pad_ints(ints):
    """Add 1 integer from min to max of the input ints list.
    Input: ints (list of ints)
    Output: ints (list of ints with an additional int for every int in the range)"""
    min_int = min(ints)
    max_int = max(ints)
    for num in range(min_int, (max_int + 1)):
        ints.append(num)
    return ints


alt.renderers.enable("altair_viewer")

my_years = [2010, 2011, 2011, 2015]
my_years = pad_ints(my_years)
counts = dict()
for i in my_years:
    # -1 is initial value, add 1 each time (even on first time)
    # so final value is 0 for empty years
    counts[i] = counts.get(i, -1) + 1
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counts, orient="index", columns=["count"])
df = df.rename_axis("year").reset_index()
df["year"] = df["year"].astype(str)
mychart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(x=alt.X("year"), y="count")

mychart.show()
```